# Powershell pipe file contents into application without loading file in memory

Tags: mysql, powershell

With `cmd` I'd run `mysql -uroot database < filename.sql` to import a database dump (read from  file and pass to MySQL).  However, `<` is "reserved" in powershell.

Instead, in powershell I use `get-content filename.sql | mysql -uroot database`.  The caveat is that powershell reads `filename.sql` *completely into memory* before passing it along to MySQL, and with large database dumps it simply runs out of memory.

Obviously, I could execute this via `cmd` but I have a handful of powershell scripts automating various tasks like this and I don't want to have to rewrite them all in batch.  In this particular case, `filename.sql` is a variable that's specified via PS parameters when the automation kicks off.

So how do I get around this memory limitation?  Is there another way to pipe the file contents into MySQL directly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can Try

```
mysql -uroot -pYourPassword -e "source C:\temp\filename.SQL"
```

or

```
mysql --user=root --password=YourPassword --execute="source C:\temp\filename.SQL"
```

If things start to get complicated maybe you should write a C# Console application that does the complex tasks.

Comment: Up and running again.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work for your application or not (it should process the file in chunks of 1000 records at a time, rather than all at once):

```
get-content filename.sql -readcount 1000 |% {$_ | mysql -uroot database}
```

Comment: Slick technique, but splitting arbitrarily on number of lines seems to mangle the SQL syntax.  This'll definitely come in handy in other places, though, thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say stay away from the cmdlets for large files. I've been doing something similar with files that are 30+ million lines long and have not had a issue by using the below code. It performs extremely well both speed-wise and memory consumption-wise.

```
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText($filetoread)
while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
   $line = $reader.ReadLine()

   #do your thing here

}
$reader.Close()
```

Comment: This will not work when single sql command is split into more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

Windows cmd (example for postgre, translate it individually):
`psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -f database.sql -U .... ....`