# Import large MySQL .sql file on Windows with Force

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, powershell, import

I would like to import a 350MB MySQL .sql file on a Windows 7 machine. I usually do this by using

```
mysql -uuser -p -e "source c:/path/to/file.sql" database
```

since < doesn't work in Powershell.

My .sql file has an error in it this time. I'd prefer to just skip the bad row and continue the import. How can I force the import to continue on Windows?

On a unix/linux based system, I could use

```
mysql --force ... < file.sql
```

but --force doesn't seem to work with the -e "source ..." command (understandably so).

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I'm trying to import from my linux box with the host option (-h). While it will probably work, I'd prefer to do this locally.

Comment: Importing from the linux computer worked well. Still interested in a Windows only solution though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably going to have to have Powershell execute this in the standard console in order to use `<` properly. Technically you could use `get-content` and pipe the output to `mysql`, but I've always found that to be slow, and it somehow still keeps the file contents in memory of the Powershell session.

This is how I would execute it from the Powershell prompt (changed file path to include spaces to demonstrate inner quotes, just in case):

```
cmd /C 'mysql -uuser -p --force < "C:\path\with spaces\to\file.sql"'
```

*`[GC]::collect()` would apparently clear it up the memory, but you can't do that until after it's done anyway. When it comes to `mysql` and `mysqldump`, I don't bother with Powershell. The default encoding used in `>` is Unicode, making dump files twice as big out of Powershell as out of `cmd` unless you remember to write `| out-file dump.sql -enc ascii` instead of `> dump.sql`.*

Comment: I noticed that with Get-Content and Powershell too. I was at 1.4 GB of RAM used before it ran out of memory.

Comment: For me --force is not working whatever i do. It stops

Comment: @SatyaPrakash: `--force` makes it continue if it encounters an error, but there are probably classes of errors from which it can't continue. You may have to actually fix your error instead of trying to ignore it.

Comment: Ya, for me it was phpmyadmin was not exporting correctly. I used mysql dump for export and import using mysql ... and promlem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to also have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789073/540776), that takes advantage of `source` SQL command: