# Why is "<" input redirect not implemented in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Why is [input redirection](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/01/09/powershell-abcs---o-is-for-output.aspx) not implemented in PowerShell?

To do something like this:

```
mysql -u root < create.sql
```

I had to switch to "cmd.exe".

Is there an alternative way of doing this in PowerShell?

Please note that the output redirection ">" is implemented in PowerShell. Please consider this before giving an answer.

Comment: Since you gave piping a script to `mysql` as your example, I thought I should [point you to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365191/import-large-mysql-sql-file-on-windows-with-force/6365553#6365553) in case you try to use Powershell to pipe a backup.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Granted, not the best solution, but a nice hack, without having to switch back to dos-prompt.

Comment: A year and a half later, I still don't have an answer to this specific question of why input redirect was not implemented.

Answer (score 13):

Although I'm not entirely sure that this question belongs on Stack Overflow, have you looked at the PS Cmdlet for [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content?view=powershell-5.1)? Look how it's used in the examples on TechNet in *[Using the Get-Content Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx)*.

Example:

```
Get-Content c:\scripts\test.txt | Foreach-Object {Get-Wmiobject -computername $_ win32_bios}
```

Update: Above link to TechNet is broken, but mentioned in comment by Chad Miller Scripting Guy's post *[Working Around Legacy Redirection Issues with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/16/working-around-legacy-redirection-issues-with-powershell/)* gives three options: -`use CMD /c`, `Echo`, and Get-Content.

Comment: Redirection was covered in a Scripting Guys post using Get-Content http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/16/working-around-legacy-redirection-issues-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: @Chad Miller, Oh, of course - that would be the obvious place for a user of powershell to look! /end-sarcasm. Thanks.

Comment: ss64.com is also an obvious place to look period; though granted, the answer at http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html is only implicit

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MySQL will accept PowerShell objects piped to it - as Stephan says though, you could use Get-Content and pipe it to the next command.

Check out Stack Overflow question *[Is PowerShell ready to replace my Cygwin shell on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/powershell-vs-unix-shells)* for reasons on why they haven't copied Unix shells.

Comment: Did you read Jeffery Snover's comment? He talks about the reasons.

Comment: I see no reasons on input redirects in particular, and I am really not interested in Unix vs Windows tools. I was only curious about the one particular tool. After all, the output redirection ">" is implemented!

Comment: I was considering the question more generically in why certain aspects of powershell do not implement the same functions as other shells. I didn't say it answered why < wasn't implemented though it provides insight into the design process,