# Input redirection for cmd from PowerShell

Tags: redirect, powershell, input, cmd

I am trying to to run mysql with input from a file.  I have found that the following works:

cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\MySQL...\mysql -u user -pPassword databasename -f < inputfilename.sql'

The problem is that the databasename ($database) and inputfilename.sql ($file) are variables and need to be interpolated.  I have not found any way to make the interpolation work.

Note that invoke-expression and & will not work because PowerShell doesn't implement < for input redirection.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had *exactly* the same need as yours. Taking example from other SO answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17666285/540776), here's what I wrote:

```
$binPath = <local MySQL bin path>
$mySql = Join-Path $binPath "mysql"
...
$dosCommand = "$mySql --host=$dbHost --user=$dbUser --password=$dbPassword $dbName --verbose < ""$scriptPath"""
cmd.exe /c $dosCommand
```

Comment: Actually I'm fixing my code now and adding double quotes, from `... < $scriptPath"` to `... < ""$scriptPath"""`, otherwise I get errors when  script path contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use Get-Content as answered in this similar question [Why is "<" input redirect not implemented in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763086/why-is-input-redirect-not-implemented-in-powershell/6763153#comment8020985_6763153)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're enclosing the entire command in single quotes.  Variables don't get interpolated in single-quoted strings.  Try this:

```
cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql' -u user -pPassword $database -f < $file
```