# Can't run python script with an txt entry in powershell [Errno 22]

Tags: python, powershell, python-3.7

I have installed python 3.7, I'm really new to this and read you can run a script with a txt entry in PowerShell (already did environment path configs).
I opened PowerShell and type:
- cd [Python script directory]
- python main_1.py

It should run but gives an error in return, [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbxIA.jpg).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need some spaxce between python filename and input text filename. try adding space between "<" so it can be "python python_file < input_file".

Answer (score 2):

Input redirection (the command line operator `<`) is [not implemented in Windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763086/why-is-input-redirect-not-implemented-in-powershell). You may want to switch to `cmd.exe` if you need this functionality.

Comment: thanks, i switch to cmd, used full path and it worked!