# Pipe stream to other process

Tags: powershell, stream, pipe

I would like to download a 20GB dump, replace strings and pipe it to mysql.exe while it still downloads in Powershell. But I'm having issues piping the stream.

If my file was already downloaded, I could stream while replacing strings in the file to StdOut with:

```
Get-Content 'dump.sql' | %{ $_.replace("production_db", "staging_db") }
```

Or if I also download the file while streaming and replacing strings to StdOut , I could do this:

```
$url = 'http://MyServer.ext/dump.sql'
& {
    $myHttpWebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("MyUsername:MyPassword")))
    try {
        $res = $myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        $res = $_.Exception.Response
    } 
    if ([int] $res.StatusCode -ne 200) {
        'Error: ' + [int]$res.StatusCode + " " + $res.StatusCode
    } else {
        $receiveStream = $res.GetResponseStream()
        $encode = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")
        $readStream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($receiveStream, $encode)
        while (-not $readStream.EndOfStream) {
            $readStream.ReadLine().replace("production_db", "staging_db")
        }
        $res.Close()
        $readStream.Close()
    }
}
```

But in both cases, I fail to pipe this as a stream to mysql.exe. It seams the whole stream is first loaded into memory, before being passed on to the mysql.exe process, when I append:

```
 | & 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe' -u MyUsername -pMyPassword -h 127.0.0.1
```

How do I manage to pipe a stream to another process in Powershell?

Comment: Afaik, external commands are unknown with the *PowerShell* pipeline, which means you need to stream each line (each *complete sql command*) separately to **mysql.exe**: `... |ForEach-Object { & 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe' -u MyUsername -pMyPassword -h 127.0.0.1 }`

Comment: @iRon I'm afraid that won't help. As it will be very slow to run another mysql.exe for each statement. And also some statements even depend on eachother (such as setting environment variables.)

Comment: @nl-x as a workaround you can try to create a `.bat` file with `type dump.sql | mysql.exe` command and execute this `.bat` file with proper arguments from PowerShell script

Comment: I think the best solution is to drop the external command `mysql.exe` and continue with .Net and com objects using a database connector. See e.g.: [Which driver should I install so that mysqlcommand can be run using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127230/1701026)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell pipe file contents into application without loading file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788935/powershell-pipe-file-contents-into-application-without-loading-file-in-memory)

Answer (score 0):

We know mysql.exe will take standard input because we can run `mysql.exe < myfile.sql` and it works great. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100200/7411885) fantastic answer about sending lines of text to the standard input of a process, and it seems to work for me. I'm using the CMD shell to test with since I don't have mysql handy:

```
# Setup: example commands to feed via stream to process
'echo "hello"
echo "world"
echo "bye"
exit' > 'C:\temp\file.bat'

# create streamreader from file
$readStream = [System.IO.Streamreader]::new('C:\temp\file.bat')
$encode = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")
```

For you, just update your replacement and the exe name:

```
# Create a process for the job
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"; #process file
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false; #start the process from it's own executable file
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true; #enable the process to read from standard input
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true #send standard output to object

$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);

# Send each line of the file to the process as standard input:
while (-not $readStream.EndOfStream) {
  $p.StandardInput.WriteLine(
    ($readStream.ReadLine().replace("l", "L"))
  )
}

$readStream.Close()

# Make sure you don't accidentally close mysql before it's done processing.
# For example, add WriteLine('exit') after the While{}, then use Wait-Process.
# get the output of the process, should also wait for the process to finish
$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$p.Close()
```

In my tests it's working, replacing the commands as they're read, and sending them to the process, and shows the output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>echo "heLLo"
"heLLo"

C:\>echo "worLd"
"worLd"

C:\>echo "bye"
"bye"

C:\>exit
```

I think you should be able to hook into $p.StandardOutput and read it as you go, but when I tried it would cause the process to hang? Maybe just use mysql logging instead.